# Double cover of $SO(2)$

Tags: covering-spaces, linear-groups

In most textbooks i found that $SPIN(2)$ group is isomorphic to $U(1)$. That is $U(1)$ is double cover of $SO(2)$. But $U(1)$ is isomorphic to $SO(2)$.
So how can it be? Does  this definition of double cover does not work for $n=2$ ?

Answer (score 3):

What's the problem? You can see $U(1)$ as a double cover of $SO(2,\mathbb{R})$:$$\begin{array}{ccc}U(1)&\longrightarrow&SO(2,\mathbb{R})\\e^{i\theta}&\mapsto&\begin{pmatrix}\cos(2\theta)&-\sin(2\theta)\\\sin(2\theta)&\cos(2\theta)\end{pmatrix}.\end{array}$$

Comment: Double cover does not mean $2->1$ map?

Comment: @amiltonmoreira Yes. And that's what happens with the map the I defined.

Comment: But if they are isomorphic how can it be?

Comment: @amiltonmoreira What's the problem? My example shows that there is no contradiction. A space *can* be a double (or triple or whatever) cover of itself.

Comment: So what you  mean is that the  map may  not be surjective

Comment: It *is* surjective. If $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}\cos\theta&-\sin\theta\\\sin\theta&\cos\theta\end{smallmatrix}\right)\in SO(2,\mathbb{R})$, then my map maps $\exp\left(\frac{i\theta}2\right)$ into it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79741/discussion-between-amilton-moreira-and-jose-carlos-santos).

Answer (score 3):

As it happens $U(1)$ is an $n$-fold cover of itself for all positive integers $n$ by the mapping $e^{it}\mapsto e^{nit}$. Therefore it is also an $n$-fold covering of $SO(2)$ for all $n$.

Comment: 2n-fold in the case SO(2,$\mathbb{R}$) no?

Comment: @hzm The mapping
$$e^{it}\mapsto\pmatrix{\cos t&-\sin t\cr \sin t&\cos t\cr}$$ is an isomorphism from $U(1)$ to $SO_2(\Bbb{R})$. So precomposing it with $e^{it}\mapsto e^{int}$ makes it an $n$-fold cover.